# Created wordpress using quick install on Hostgator but unable to access the URLS

Tags: plugins

My problem is that I've installed wordpress on Hostgator using quickinstall but unable to access the URLS. Just bought the domain name few hours ago on namecheap.

[image]

I received an email already and here is the screenshot

[image]

After clicking on one of the URLS it shows page does not exist

Comment: Your domain probably hasn't propagated yet. Whenever you buy a new domain or change nameservers, it takes a day or two (up to 72 hours) before that info is copied across the internet.

Comment: I bought the domain name but do i need to configure the sub URL? For example, `www.example.com/blog` on namecheap.com because i just bought the domain name.

Comment: You have to set DNS settings on your domain, in Namecheap, so that it knows to point to HostGator's server. Please refer to HostGator's documentation or support as this request is off-topic here.